# How can i put SlidingDrawer as a system overlay?

Tags: java, android, service, overlay, slidingdrawer

How can i put SlidingDrawer as a system overlay(or show it always on top)?
I will use service to show it, but i don't know how to do it(showing SlidingDrawer as a system overlay using Service) How can i do it like [this pic](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kgurQ50Rf4g/URIVpRSUP1I/AAAAAAAADVc/Ja7yXEKzf4k/s787/example.png)? any tutorials or sample sources?

Comment: Fount a solution? i'm looking for the same 

[jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu / Is there a way to avoid sliding the main view when menu is opening?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566678/jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-sliding-the-main-view-when-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SlidingMenu Library as the default android sliding drawer is deprecated.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu